# SSRS - How to execute multiple instances of the same report simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've got an SSIS package - the primary function of which is to precalculate some data and invoke an parameterized SSRS report. The SSRS report has multiple datasets, that it retrieves through stored procedures. It takes around 2-2.5 seconds to generate.

When I loop through the report within the package, the loop obviously executes one report at a time. To speed up this process, I split up the dataset into two and tried passing each dataset into its own loop container. The problem is that although the loops process simultaneously, the step at which the report is generated (script task) halts the process for the other loop - that is, while one report is generating, the other waits.

Given this, it seems that SSRS locks and only allows for one execution at a time. The profiler showed "sp_WriteLockSession" being invoked but [according to this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98664/ssrs-blocking-processes) it appears that that is based on the design. I've also read up on the "no lock" hint but I'm not sure that's the route I want to go down either.

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this in the right way. Am I missing something? The only other thing I can think of is to create a second report and invoke that instead but if its locking due to the underlying datasets, then I'm really not sure what else to do. The datasets are primarily just select statements, with a couple of them inserting one row into a single table at the very end.

I'd appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!